# Was Gödel already a Platonist when he discovered/proved his incompleteness theorems?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

Since when was Gödel a platonist? Was he already a platonist when he discovered/proved his incompleteness theorems?

Comment: Very useful recent collection of essays : Juliette Kennedy (editor), [Interpreting Gödel : Critical Essays](https://books.google.it/books?id=ulw3BAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2014).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kurt Gödel was already a Platonist by that time. In fact - he presumed Platonism to be true already when he wrote his dissertation where he proved his completeness theorem. His belief in Platonism only grew stronger after he came up with his famous incompleteness theorems.

See SE http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel/ for general review about his work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure quite what you mean by being a Platonist:

Do you mean solely in terms of how he saw the status of mathematical objects ie Mathematical Platonism?

But if one answers this: *yea*, or *nay*; does this in fact describe Godels philosophy, or does it do it a gross injustice - by gross reduction? Reducing a many-sided man to a one-sided philosophy?

After all, the word 'is' posits an identity, or suggests it.

Or do you mean in terms of Neo-Platonism, which is closer to Platos theory of forms?

Given that Godel devised his own version of Anselms ontological proof of God, and that he [read](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_ontological_proof) the:

> 'Bible in bed every Sunday morning'

and that he said

> 'religions are bad, but religion is not'

I'd suggest he was closer to the intermingling of neo-platonist thought and Christian doctrine which occurred in its critical early formation.

For whereas with Badiou, who is described by Zizek as a platonist - as in fact a neo-Plato, posits the axiom that the 'One is not'; Godel posits the axiom the One is.